# Setting sound on notification channel doesn't play my custom sound (but plays another sound instead)

Tags: android, android-notifications

When the notification comes it plays a sound but it's not my custom sound. Here's my code to set the sound of the Channel. What do I need to change?

```
 private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
      Uri ringtone = Uri.parse("android.resource://" +  getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/" +R.raw.videocall);

      CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
      String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
      int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
      NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CustomFirebaseMessagingService.CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
      channel.setDescription(description);
      AudioAttributes.Builder audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
              .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE);
     channel.setSound(ringtone,audioAttributes.build());


      // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
      // or other notification behaviors after this
      NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
      notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
      Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Created notification channel");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Possible causes:

Is the device you're running this on Android Orio plus?

Comment: getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) never saw this way getSystemService(NotificationManager.class)

Comment: You can try modifying the Audio attributes

AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
            .build();

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Android. I tried changing .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION) .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM) 

Didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

OK I didn't need to change the code. I think Android somehow cached the old sound. To fix I simply changed the channel id when creating the NotificationChannel to something else so Android woudn't use the cached sound file.